# Connection to the Spark Cluster from local machine

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cluster-computing

I am running Spark Cluster ( Master and 3 Workers ) and I am connecting to it from my local application that I run on the local box.

In my application I create a Dataset

```
List<String> points = Arrays.asList("UK", "US", "France", "Italy");
Dataset<String> dataset = spark.createDataset(points, Encoders. STRING());
```

that works perfectly fine and I can see that Dataset is created by running.

```
dataset.show()
```

Then I am trying to write it to the parquet file to the local drive

```
dataset.write().mode(SaveMode.Append)
                .parquet(<Hadoop Path>);
```

and an application just hangs with the following message getting logged all the time :

```
WARN  org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl - Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

Is it a configuration issue?

Answer (score 0):

The code itself looks good to me.
In terms of the `WARN`, even though there is a possibility that it is from some configuration, however, you did not show them. Nobody could guess.

But I'd recommend you firstly enlarge your data size and give it a try. Try with a much bigger example, with not only 4 elements, cause only 4 elements, when split, some executor might get nothing to feed.

Comment: Thank you! It's interesting I updated a StoragePath to my local drive and a folder in named after the cache name was created, however it was empty. I will try more data.